# I am not getting output in the fucntion below why?

Tags: python, string

```
s = input()
k=input()
def string():
    n=0
    index=0
    while (k+n)<len (s):
        string= s[index:(k+n)]
        index+=1
        n+=1
    return string
```

I want to return the substrings of the input string

Answer (score 0):

First of all indent the code

```
s = input()
k=input()
def string():
    n=0
    index=0 
    while (k+n)<len (s):
        string= s[index:(k+n)]
        index+=1
        n+=1
    return string
```

afterwards make sure when your calling the function make use of print function 
Ex `print(string())`

Comment: With the above indented code i am not getting any ouput. I am getting  TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: oh got it , use len(k)+n as k is string and n is integer that's why you are getting an error

Comment: bro k is integer only..that is the length of the substring and i am taking that as five